# Maven Compilation Error using Spring Boot with Cassandra

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, spring-data-cassandra

I am setting up a Spring Boot application with Cassandra repository. Maven has gone rogue though, because the application **stopped compiling.** Spring Data Cassandra is not getting handled properly. Everything in "org.springframework.cassandra.core.mapping" *does not exist* locally. And it looks like I have other packages "...cassandra.core" that are OK.

Cassandra bean mapping classes like @Table, @Column, etc. fail with "cannot find symbol" in Maven compilation. I tried cleaning, and even tried deleting my ./.m2/repository, but it cannot compile. I expect some version mismatch must be happening, or it could be time to start using Gradle.

I have run "jar tvf spring-data-cassandra-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar | grep 'mapping'" and the mapping.* classes **are all present.** Yet, "mvn clean compile" results in multiple homogeneous errors of:

> [ERROR]
>   /media/kevvurs/ExtraDrive1/winshare/workspace/FPSJobsRedesign/FPSDistributionFilter/src/main/java/com/shc/scinventory/dfilter/data/DcUnitInfoBean.java:[4,55]
>   package org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.mapping does not exist

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.sample.app</groupId>
<artifactId>Filter</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>Filter</name>
<description>Command-line tool</description>
<properties>
    <maven.antrun.plugin.version>1.7</maven.antrun.plugin.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <jdk.version>1.8</jdk.version>
</properties>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-cassandra</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.beust</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcommander</artifactId>
        <version>1.72</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.8.13</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
        <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.17</version>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
                    <artifactId>surefire-testng</artifactId>
                    <version>2.17</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <configuration>
                <groups>dev</groups>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>test</phase>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: There were changes in Spring Data Cassandra 2.0 regarding packages but you're using version 1.5.x, that's what is pulled in by Spring Boot 1.5.9.

Comment: Yes, everything is 1.5.9. All I can think of now is Java language level discrepancy, or a version mismatch somewhere/somehow. I even rebooted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved**
I was integrating a class that uses a different, non-Boot, configuration of Spring. I had tried importing @Table and other Spring Data annotations from: org.springframework.data.cassandra.**core**.mapping.Table when it is provided in org.springframework.data.cassandra.mapping.Table for when using spring-boot-starter-data-cassandra.

**Conclusion**
I sometimes depend too much on Intellij and tools for refactoring and auto-completing things. The problem would have been obvious if I had paid more attention.